# Looping through an array and comparing values for each category and returning the highest scoring one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a test app on my web where a user can see a check list, mark all that applies and get a result based on what he picked.

Every question has a category and a value, and id like to get the category that had the highest score (add all the values for each category and return the highest)

I have been somewhat successful, with the code below i get all the answered question scores added together, not taking into account what category each question belongs to

```
      @test_session.answered_questions.each do |a|
        if a.answer == 1
          @theResult.score = @theResult.score + a.q_value
        end    
        @theResult.save!
      end
```

the questions are check boxes so if `answer == 1` the check box was marked

The problem is that the number of categories is dynamic..

i had an idea that i could loop through `@test_session.answered_questions.category.each` add the categories value to some variables and compare when all category scores have been calculated BUT then again i would have a dynamic number of variables to compare

i feel like there is some map function i should use for this

**UPDATE**

here is how i set questions category attribute

```
<%= nested_form_for @personal_test do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Description" %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.label "Question" %>
  <%= ff.text_field :question_text %>

  <%= ff.label "Question value" %>
  <%= ff.number_field :value %>

  <%= ff.select :category, options_for_select(Category.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, :selected => ff.object.category), :prompt => 'Category' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will want to do something like this. I put comments in the code to try and explain it.

```
#loop through all categories...
@test_session.answered_questions.category.each do |c|
   sum = 0
   #loop through every questions in current category
   c.answered_questions.each do |a|
      if a.answer == 1
         sum += a.q_value
      end
   end
   #keep track of the highest score and category as we go along...
   #we can forget about the rest
   if @theResult.score.nil? or sum > @theResult.score
      @theResult.score = sum
      @theResult.category = c
   end 
end

#theResult now holds the category with the highest score

@theResult.save!
```

Comment: yes i believe this is exactly what i was trying to do thanks but im getting a error that `answered_questions.category.each` is an undefined method, its not really a method but a string attribute that each question has, ill uppdate my post an show you how i set it

Comment: I will need your model code to tell you exactly how the loops should look. The comments tell you exactly what you want to loop through so if you can't figure it out yourself post your model code.

Comment: well i dont think my models would help since they are pretty empty save for attr_accessors, i do understand the code you wrote and it does help a lot - but i think my proble is that `category` isnt a model its an attribute so i cant use the `.each` function

Comment: in your form code you are using `Category.all.collect` so you have a Category class at the very least. Anyways, its your relations in your model code that matter for this, (ie. `has_many`, `has_one`...). If you don't have those set up properly doing what you are trying to do could get extremely difficult.

Comment: yeah i do have a category model but its not connected to the questions.. but probably it should, maybe i should just make question belong to category, lol why didnt i think of that.. instead i was trying to create that category string that refereed back to the category id

Comment: Yeah... it definitely should be connected. Your best bet would be to make questions belong to `Category` (change `category` value to `category_id`) then you can do the loops with `Category.each do |c|` and then `c.questions.each do |a|`

Comment: questions belong to category now but im not sure i got the rest, care to elaborate ? :P